# How do I disable the script for the mobile version of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I customized the cursor on my site. It is now in the shape of a dot. But when I click anywhere on the mobile version of the site, that dot appears. This is very disturbing.
How do I disable the code for the mobile version of the site? I need the script not to work on devices less than 1200 pixels wide

```
<style>

html, 
html *, 
body, 
body * {
        cursor: none;
}
.cursor-dot,
.cursor-dot-outline {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cursor-dot {
  z-index:99999999;
  width: 10.0px;
  height: 10.0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #000;
}

.cursor-dot-outline {
  z-index:99999998;
  width: 0.0px;
  height: 0.0px;
  background-color: rgba(169, 169, 222, 0.2);
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #000;
}

</style>

<script>
    
    $("body").prepend('<div class="cursor-dot-outline"></div>');
    $("body").prepend('<div class="cursor-dot"></div>');

    var cursor = {
    delay: 8,
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    endX: (window.innerWidth / 2),
    endY: (window.innerHeight / 2),
    cursorVisible: true,
    cursorEnlarged: false,
    $dot: document.querySelector('.cursor-dot'),
    $outline: document.querySelector('.cursor-dot-outline'),
    
    init: function() {
        this.dotSize = this.$dot.offsetWidth;
        this.outlineSize = this.$outline.offsetWidth;
        
        this.setupEventListeners();
        this.animateDotOutline();
    },

    setupEventListeners: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(el) {
            el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                self.cursorEnlarged = true;
                self.toggleCursorSize();
            });
            el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
                self.cursorEnlarged = false;
                self.toggleCursorSize();
            });
        });
        
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            self.cursorEnlarged = true;
            self.toggleCursorSize();
        });
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
            self.cursorEnlarged = false;
            self.toggleCursorSize();
        });
  
  
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            self.cursorVisible = true;
            self.toggleCursorVisibility();

            self.endX = e.clientX;
            self.endY = e.clientY;
            self.$dot.style.top = self.endY + 'px';
            self.$dot.style.left = self.endX + 'px';
        });
        
        document.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
            self.cursorVisible = true;
            self.toggleCursorVisibility();
            self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
            self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
        });
        
        document.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
            self.cursorVisible = true;
            self.toggleCursorVisibility();
            self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
            self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
        });
    },
    
    animateDotOutline: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        self._x += (self.endX - self._x) / self.delay;
        self._y += (self.endY - self._y) / self.delay;
        self.$outline.style.top = self._y + 'px';
        self.$outline.style.left = self._x + 'px';
        
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animateDotOutline.bind(self));
    },
    
    toggleCursorSize: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        if (self.cursorEnlarged) {
            self.$dot.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(4)';
            self.$outline.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)';
        } else {
            self.$dot.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)';
            self.$outline.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)';
        }
    },
    
    toggleCursorVisibility: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        if (self.cursorVisible) {
            self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
            self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
            self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }
}
cursor.init();

        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place this at the beginning of the script:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 1200) {
  throw new Error("Site is on mobile")
}
```

This will stop the execution of the script if the width is under 1200, as you want.

Comment: It didn't work 

Comment: is the width of the device really under 1200? Also make sure you are loading the page and the width is already 1200, if you resize your screen after the page load the script will already be ran.

Comment: I realized my mistake. Thank you very much for your help! Have an amazing day 